# Find people in my contacts using the app

Tags: android, contacts

How can I get a list of my phonebook contacts who have installed the same application on their phone.Get a list of my contacts with app X on their phone,how do I add that feature?

Comment: Read contacts of phone and store them to your server and retrieve them on app by you server

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer on android [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names#java)

```
 /*
     * Defines an array that contains column names to move from
     * the Cursor to the ListView.
     */
    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private final static String[] FROM_COLUMNS = {
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
                    >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY :
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
    };
    /*
     * Defines an array that contains resource ids for the layout views
     * that get the Cursor column contents. The id is pre-defined in
     * the Android framework, so it is prefaced with "android.R.id"
     */
    private final static int[] TO_IDS = {
           android.R.id.text1
    };
    // Define global mutable variables
    // Define a ListView object
    ListView contactsList;
    // Define variables for the contact the user selects
    // The contact's _ID value
    long contactId;
    // The contact's LOOKUP_KEY
    String contactKey;
    // A content URI for the selected contact
    Uri contactUri;
    // An adapter that binds the result Cursor to the ListView
    private SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
```